# serialization problem in gwt

Tags: java, gwt

I have read that:

[GWT serialization issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2862391/gwt-serialization-issue)

but there is no the solution.

my packages are:

package gwt.web
package gwt.web.client;
etc...

and i have package **models**

Where is located my class 'models.Word'

As you can see this class is located not int gwt.cleint, but it should not be there, it is not client side class.

this class has default constructor, so this is not issue.

I have exception:

> Service method 'public abstract java.util.List
>   gwt.web.client.WordService.getWords(java.lang.String)' threw an
>   unexpected exception:
>   com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.SerializationException: Type
>   'models.Word' was not included in the set of types which can be
>   serialized by this SerializationPolicy or its Class object could not
>   be loaded. For security purposes, this type will not be serialized.:
>   instance = Word[null]

in my App.gwt.xml:

```
<!-- Specify the paths for translatable code                    -->
<source path='models'/>
```

so this poits to my class. so, it should not be the issue as well.

The question: how to handle that? I need use my models classes to pass its by ajax by Services.

My Class is serializable (implements that interface).

This class is part of my code. This class used in RPC:

```
@RemoteServiceRelativePath("wordServiceImpl")
public interface WordService extends RemoteService {
    public List<Word> getWords(String langCode);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One key thing to keep in mind is that GWT optimizes and does not serialize all classes if not required.

If your class is not part of any RPC call (i.e. classes used in RPC call don't have this class object as a data member), GWT would not serialize this class as it assumes its not needed.

Is this the case with your code? In that case, just add a fake data member of this class to a class used in RPC

Comment: This is my code. This class used in RPC: @RemoteServiceRelativePath("wordServiceImpl")
public interface WordService extends RemoteService {
    public List<Word> getWords(String langCode);
}

Comment: I think you should try to make an object of this class as a dummy argument in RPC call and test if it serializes then

Comment: i found it's a quite stupid duplicate my entities as dummy object (in fact ast TDO objects) in client side. This leads to lots code to support. If I change some field in my entity I should change it in dummy object. It is not nice. It's interesting the general approach how people handle this problem, how they use GWT and transfer objects.. then create special protocol for that?

Comment: i found the solution as described here: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html - using Gilead. but i did not try it yet. but it seems not bad.