# Gilead for GWT with playframework

Tags: java, gwt, playframework

Based on this issue: [serialization problem in gwt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248661/serialization-problem-in-gwt) , i have read this article: http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/articles/using_gwt_with_hibernate.html

and found that Gilead might be a good solution for transferring entities by RPC.

But how to configure it for playframework?

Comment: "Unfortunately, Gilead must now be considered as an inactive project" (quote Bruno Marchesson, Author of Gilead), http://sourceforge.net/projects/gilead/forums/forum/868076/topic/4525959

Comment: ok. i see. but I've just understood what actually white-list and what actually dummy-objects is and what is for, in gwt. So, this question is not actual now.

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure this is going to be easy. From looking at the sample code from the link you posted, it would appear that the RPC is implemented by extending a Servlet class. As Play does not implement the Servlet specification, you cannot easily use servlets.

Play does have a servlet wrapper, specifically for deploying to Servlet containers, such as Tomcat, so you could take a look at the ServletWrapper to see if you could do something similar.

However, can you not achieve what you are looking for, simply by using REST and JSON?

Comment: I would also look for a bypass rather than a complete different communication system. That means that you will have to hack play framework which is not a safe operation. (updates, security, etc.)

Comment: you mean i will hack gwt-application, gwt security, etc. yes. it is so. it seems. but I've just understood what actually white-list and what actually dummy-objects is and what is for, in gwt. So, this question is not actual now.